# Only read self-made r packages In RStudio

Tags: r, package

I want to use my package without uploading githab or cran because of using that in my local.

I use devtools::install_local('C:/Users/R/package/test.zip'), but it seems failed and shows the following message.
What should I do?

```
These packages have more recent versions available.
Which would you like to update?

1: All                                
2: CRAN packages only                 
3: None                               
4: backports (1.1.4  -> 1.1.5 ) [CRAN]
5: digest    (0.6.20 -> 0.6.22) [CRAN]

Installing 1 packages: rlang
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/rlang_0.4.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1092063 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Error: Failed to install 'test.zip' from local:
  (converted from warning) cannot remove prior installation of package ‘rlang’
```

Comment: I don't know, but I tend to use `devtools::load("...")` or `install.package(devtools::build("..."))`.

Comment: Whenever I see the installation error of *"cannot remove prior installation of package ..."*, I find the only way around it is to restart R completely (no use of `./.RData` for projects) and re-install the culprit package.

Comment: >r2evans Thanks. I can do that following your advice.